# Get last 3 folders from folder path - separated by forward slash - using bash

Tags: bash, path, subdirectory, csv

I have variable x set to the the current working directory. For example.

x = this/is/an/important/folder/path

How do i iterate through this path in bash and get the last 3 folders only as per the below?

important/folder/path

Please note that the number of folders will vary, but i always need the last 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a ton of ways to do this. here's one.

```
awk -F '/' '{printf "%s/%s/%s\n", $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $NF }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="this/is/an/important/folder/path"
pattern="^(.*\/){0,1}(.*\/.*\/.*)$"

[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

**output:**

```
# ./test.sh
important/folder/path
```

Comment: Not if string="important/foldar/path"

Comment: @Wahbivic, thank you for pointing it out, I was assuming that the string has more than three components. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This may work too

```
x=this/is/an/important/folder/path
IFS='/' xx=( $x )
IFS=$' \t\n'
l=${#xx[@]}
for i in $(seq $((l-3)) $((l-1)))
do
    printf '/%s' "${xx[i]}"
done
printf '\n'
```

splitting into an array and then printing the last 3 elements